# Using jquery in Ember-cli

Tags: jquery, ember.js, ember-cli

I am relatively new to both Ember.js and Ember-cli and would really appreciate some help please with using a jquery tooltip in a custom view. All code is below, but when my template is injected, I get the following console error:

```
[Error] TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'Ember.$().tooltip()')
```

I am using a custom view in a file called tooltip.js:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.View.extend({

  tagName:  'span',
  title:  'The tooltip title',
  html: true,
  placement:  'top',
  didInsertElement: function(){
    Ember.$().tooltip({"html": this.get('html'),  
                                        "title":this.get('title'),
                                        "placement":this.get('placement'), 
                                        container: 'body'});

  }
});
```

The relevant template code is:

```
{{#view "tooltip" titleBinding="item" placement="right"}}<span><img class="app_info_icon" id="typeInfoIcon" src="/assets/images/info_icon.png"></img></span>{{/view}}
```

How can I fix this please?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Solved as follows:

- Jquery's widgets etc. are not included in the standard jquery
  library which ember-cli uses. It has to be added using `bower install --save jquery-ui`
- You then have to add the following lines to Brocfile.js:

`app.import('bower_components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js');
app.import('bower_components/jquery-ui/ui/tooltip.js');`

- As @Leeft pointed out, when referencing jQuery from a view or
  component `this.$()` should be used, not `Ember.$()`
- Be sure to use a version of Ember-CLI after 0.40.

Comment: You can also use `ember install:bower jquery-ui` instead of `bower install --save jquery-ui`.

Comment: While writing test cases, do I import jQuery UI in test files after adding it to Brocfile.js ?

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues in the code but just regarding error, Its coz you need to import the `tooltip` library(js file) into ember-cli. It is done in brocfile.js  before calling `app.toTree()` like below

`app.import('vendor/tooltip.js');`

Follow the link for more details.
http://www.ember-cli.com/#managing-dependencies

Comment: I thought that the tooltip is part of the standard jquery library? Also, would you please let me know what the other issues is in my code that you have noticed?

Comment: I spot one problem, `Ember.$().tooltip` rather than `this.$().tooltip()`. In a `View` or `Component` (Components are subclasses of Views) `this.$()` returns the jQuery element that was created by that view. `Ember.$().tooltip() would be talking to the root of the document instead.

Comment: @Leeft thanks for your comment. I changed it to `this.$()` but the same error is still appearing. I also looked into @CodeJack's suggestion that I need to import tooltip.js, but I cant find it as a  standalone lib as it appears to be part of the standard jquery library - am I correct in this or missing something?

Comment: Dependency Management in Ember CLI

Ember CLI uses two package managers: Bower, for keeping front-end dependencies (including jQuery, Ember, and QUnit) up-to-date, and npm, for managing internal dependencies. You can use both package managers to introduce your own dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Try `ember-cli tool-tipster`.....works great.