# jQuery UI with Ember CLI

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, ember-cli

So I'm pretty much having the exact problem listed here: [Using jquery in Ember-cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25424562/using-jquery-in-ember-cli)

But I've already done the following as recommended in the thread above:

Added:

```
app.import('bower_components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js');
app.import('bower_components/jquery-ui/ui/tooltip.js');
```

Changed

```
Ember.$(selector).tooltip();
```

to

```
this.$(selector).tooltip();
```

Ember isn't recognizing the tooltip function as being defined despite UI being installed and doing the above.

Error:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Any help?

Comment: You added the import to the brocfile right? and Ember.$ should work just fine

Comment: @PatsyIssa Yeah, I did and before the export as one should. I've seen both -- people have said that for views and components that you should use this.$ but neither works... :\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I had imported Ember Data which was causing an error (apparently it's imported by default or the options were stated incorrectly). Once I removed that, UI is now working properly.

Thank you for all your help Sam!

Answer (score 5):

A few things. First, `jquery-ui.js` is the entire jQuery UI library. So, you've already got `tooltip` in there. Remove that second line.

If you *only* want the tooltip, you'll need to import `core`, `widget` and `position` separately ([reference](http://jqueryui.com/download/#!version=1.11.2&components=1101000000000000000010000000000000000)), and then the `tooltip`.

Finally, you probably want to include a theme. The default one lives here:

```
app.import('bower_components/jquery-ui/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css');
```

With that, stick the `this.$().tooltip()` in your view's `didInsertElement` callback and you should be good to go.

Comment: Still saying it's undefined. I'm at a loss for words... I appreciate your willingness to help me though.

Comment: Did you just try `this.$().tooltip()`? i.e. don't put a string in for selector

Comment: Good catch! I just changed that but it's still saying it's undefined. 

I can see the imports in my vendor.js file, but I cannot find any of the definitions (i.e. tooltip) in the global namespace when using the browser inspector. It makes no sense to me

Comment: I can see it defined in the UI js file here:
    `var tooltip = $.widget( "ui.tooltip", {
 version: "1.11.2",
 options: {`

I just don't understand why it cannot find it...

Comment: have you restarted ember server?

Comment: If you mean ctrl+c and then "ember server", yes. I've restarted it multiple times. I even hopped in the jQuery IRC to get support and nobody seemed to know anything about it.

Comment: Sam, I got the UI working; however, the theme import statement doesn't seem to be changing the look of the tooltip as demonstrated on the themeroller. Do I have to do somethign else?