# Unable to load jquery plugins in Ember

Tags: jquery, ember.js, ember-cli

First of all: I already tried this answer: [Using jquery in Ember-cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25424562/using-jquery-in-ember-cli)
which seems to be the canonical way of adding a jQuery plugin to ember.

I was following this tutorial: http://beerlington.com/blog/2015/01/22/jquery-inputmask-user-experience-in-emberjs/

I installed the plugins using bower, and then added the imports to Brocfile.js.

Here's my **Brocfile.js**:

```
/* global require, module */

var EmberApp = require('ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app');

var app = new EmberApp({
  compassOptions: {
    outputStyle: 'expanded'
  }
});

app.import('bower_components/ember-uploader/dist/ember-uploader.js');
app.import('bower_components/moment/moment.js');
app.import('bower_components/jquery.inputmask/dist/jquery.inputmask.bundle.min.js');

module.exports = app.toTree();
```

The components are all correctly located at their import paths thanks to bower.

And here's the component at **components/input-mask.js**:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.TextField.extend({
  initializeMask: function() {
    var mask = this.get('mask');

    this.$().inputmask(mask, {
      onBeforeMask: function(value) {
        if (mask === 'mm/dd/yyyy') {
          return moment(new Date(value)).format('L');
        }
      }
    });

    // The input mask changes the value of the input from the original to a
    // formatted version. We need to manually send that change back to the
    // controller.
    this.set('value', this.$().val());
  }.on('didInsertElement')
});
```

But in Chrome's console I get the error: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` for `this.$().inputmask`.

Am I missing something else to import a plugin to jQuery?

Comment: Is `$.inputmask` undefined?

Comment: Did you rerun the broc file?

Comment: @JordyLangen yes, $.inputmask is undefined too.

Comment: @Bloomfield I'm using Ember CLI to serve the app, I always thought it used the brocfile on its own. How should I rerun the broc file?

Comment: @jrlainfiesta Yeah it the ember serve command runs broccoli, but if you import new files into the broc file, you have to rerun the ember serve command so the files get uploaded.

Comment: Oh I see, rerunning  `ember serve` doesn't work either. The plugin still appears as undefined.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved after I restarted my computer and issued `ember serve` again. I guess my computer was doing something weird caching where it shouldn't have.

Comment: After adding the file paths to your Brocfile.js, did you close the ember server, the start again? You need to do that every time you alter that file so the changes are picked up.