# Ember JQuery UI import overrides JQuery $ Behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I need JQuery UI for dragging and dropping objects in my Ember app. So, after installing via `yarn`, I import it in the project's `ember-cli-build.js` as follows:

```
app.import('bower_components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js', {
    using: [{ transformation: 'fastbootShim' }]
});
```

It gets loaded successfully and drag-drop works fine. However, the form functionality in other part of my codebase breaks with the following error:

```
TypeError: Ember.$.fn.form.settings is undefined
```

In this file, `$` is imported from jQuery: `import $ from 'jquery';`

I suspect the import of `jquery-ui` overrides the behaviour of `$` and causes this error. How do I fix this? Am I missing something obvious? Please help, I'm an Ember newbie.

Comment: Just guessing: Try `import 'jquery-ui';` after the `import $ from 'jquery';`

Comment: Might also help to use `ember-auto-import` to import npm packages:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51766188/jqueryui-at-ember-upgrade

Comment: @enspandi In which file should I do that? Also, for the question you mentioned in the 2nd comment - I had a bounty on it of 100 pts :), didn't help.

Comment: @SamChats do you need jQuery? (my preference is to remove it from ember entirely and never touch it again)

Comment: Another option is to replace your use of $ with this.element and use native DOM helpers for everything but the ui library. Depending on your codebase size, that might be workable if you run out of options http://youmightnotneedjquery.com This problem with globals is a good reason to try and remove it from Bower as a first step.

Comment: @NullVoxPopuli Can't remove it, it's a needed dependency as of now :(

Comment: What I mean is that if you have to use this dependency and it’s overriding Ember.$, you could stop using $ everywhere else, possibly